# Segue to different categories from Collection View

Tags: swift, firebase, carousel

Edit: I am on the right track, but the button can only point to 1 ViewController

I used

```
    @IBAction func viewTouchedBttn(_ sender: Any) {
    print("touched")
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {



        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            print("1")
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "1", sender: nil)
        case 1:
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "2", sender: nil)
        case 2:
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "3", sender: nil)
        default:
            break
        }

    }
```

I recently done the tutorial about building a carousel in swift with a UICollectionView as taught in this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vB-HKnhOgl8 ( you can download it as well so we would have the same basis)

I am quit new to coding so I am sorry if this is quit obvious for you and I don't get it ^^.

Each category should point to a different vc by clicking on the cell.

When I press on the View with "Travel the world" the segue should point to the VC where you can talk about Travel, if I am interested in building apps and click on that view, I want to be directed to this specific category.

Thanks for your help! :)

edit: files

InterestCollectionView

```
class InterestCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell
{
@IBOutlet weak var featuredImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var interestTitleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var backgroundColorView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var kategorie: UILabel!

var interest: Interest? {
    didSet {
        self.updateUI()
    }
}

private func updateUI()
{
    if let interest = interest {
        kategorie.text = interest.kategorie
        featuredImageView.image = interest.featuredImage
        interestTitleLabel.text = interest.title
        backgroundColorView.backgroundColor = interest.color
    } else {
        featuredImageView.image = nil
        interestTitleLabel.text = nil
        backgroundColorView.backgroundColor = nil
    }
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    self.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0
    layer.shadowRadius = 10
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5, height: 10)

    self.clipsToBounds = false
}
}
```

interest file

```
class Interest
{
// MARK: - Public API
var kategorie = ""
var title = ""
var featuredImage: UIImage
var color: UIColor

init(title: String, featuredImage: UIImage, color: UIColor, kategorie: String)
{
    self.kategorie = kategorie
    self.title = title
    self.featuredImage = featuredImage
    self.color = color
}

// MARK: - Private
// dummy data
static func fetchInterests() -> [Interest]
{
    return [
        Interest(title: "Travelling Around the World", featuredImage: UIImage(named: "f1")!, color: UIColor(red: 63/255.0, green: 71/255.0, blue: 80/255.0, alpha: 0.8), kategorie: "Forum"),
        Interest(title: "Cafe with Best Friends", featuredImage: UIImage(named: "f2")!, color: UIColor(red: 240/255.0, green: 133/255.0, blue: 91/255.0, alpha: 0.8), kategorie: "Forum"),
        Interest(title: "Study Personal Development Books and Courses", featuredImage: UIImage(named: "f3")!, color: UIColor(red: 105/255.0, green: 80/255.0, blue: 227/255.0, alpha: 0.8), kategorie: "Post"),
        Interest(title: "Build Amazing iOS Apps", featuredImage: UIImage(named: "f4")!, color: UIColor(red: 102/255.0, green: 102/255.0, blue: 102/255.0, alpha: 0.8), kategorie: "Forum"),

        Interest(title: "Learn. Create. Contribute.", featuredImage: UIImage(named: "f5")!, color: UIColor(red: 245/255.0, green: 62/255.0, blue: 40/255.0, alpha: 0.8),kategorie: "Forum"),
        Interest(title: "Inspire, Instruct, and Empower People", featuredImage: UIImage(named: "f6")!, color: UIColor(red: 103/255.0, green: 217/255.0, blue: 87/255.0, alpha: 0.8), kategorie: "Bilder"),
        Interest(title: "Business and Marketing Geeks", featuredImage: UIImage(named: "f7")!, color: UIColor(red: 63/255.0, green: 71/255.0, blue: 80/255.0, alpha: 0.8), kategorie: "Forum"),
        Interest(title: "3D Printing, Virtual Reality and AI", featuredImage: UIImage(named: "f8")!, color: UIColor(red: 240/255.0, green: 133/255.0, blue: 91/255.0, alpha: 0.8), kategorie: "Forum"),
        Interest(title: "Einzeiler", featuredImage: UIImage(named: "f3")!, color: UIColor(red: 30/255.0, green: 20/255.0, blue: 130/255.0, alpha: 0.8), kategorie: "Forum")
    ]
}
}
```

the interest ViewController

```
import UIKit

class InterestsViewController: UIViewController
{
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

var interests = Interest.fetchInterests()
let cellScaling: CGFloat = 0.6

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
    let cellWidth = floor(screenSize.width * cellScaling)
    let cellHeight = floor(screenSize.height * cellScaling)

    let insetX = (view.bounds.width - cellWidth) / 2.0
    let insetY = (view.bounds.height - cellHeight) / 2.0

    let layout = collectionView!.collectionViewLayout as!     UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight)
    collectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: insetY, left: insetX, bottom: insetY, right: insetX)

    collectionView?.dataSource = self
    collectionView?.delegate = self
}
}

extension InterestsViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource
{
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return interests.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "InterestCell", for: indexPath) as! InterestCollectionViewCell

    cell.interest = interests[indexPath.item]

    return cell
}
}

extension InterestsViewController : UIScrollViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegate
{
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>)
{
    let layout = self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    let cellWidthIncludingSpacing = layout.itemSize.width + layout.minimumLineSpacing

    var offset = targetContentOffset.pointee
    let index = (offset.x + scrollView.contentInset.left) / cellWidthIncludingSpacing
    let roundedIndex = round(index)

    offset = CGPoint(x: roundedIndex * cellWidthIncludingSpacing - scrollView.contentInset.left, y: -scrollView.contentInset.top)
    targetContentOffset.pointee = offset
}
}
```

Comment: Paste some code here. The idea is not to have to go to a website to see your code.

Comment: And where is the segue you're using? It's made in storyboard completely?

Comment: i am trying to post the code but theres´s an error occurring all the time I don't know why I will try further

Comment: Okay added all of them didn't format it quit well

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options to do what you want.

For example you could add in your storyboard a storyboard reference to controller you want to segue to, or a view controller if it's in the same storyboard. And then ctrl + drag from the view to the view controller (or storyboard reference) that you want to segue to. There you will have the different segues types (show, push, etc).
That's the full storyboard way of doing it.

There are multiple other options. But that may be the easiest.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html

**EDIT:**

You can also create 8 segues from the controller (ctrl + drag from controller) to other controllers or storyboard references. Then click on the segues created and in the identifier inspector name every segue with a unique identifier.

Then when you click on the cell you can determine which cell was clicked and perform the segue you need for that cell with `performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier, sender)`

Comment: I have 1 cell which stands for the 8 different categories, so I need segue to 8 different storyboards and thats what I cannot accomplish.

Comment: and where do I call the perform segue then?

Comment: Implement function `collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`

Comment: okay i have, now I have to distinguish between each selected view. I tried with the index path but that did not work, I try with case now?

Comment: I used  if index path.row == 0 { perform segue ...} else {...} (just for 2 categories to test for now) and a print command but nothing shows up

Comment: if indexPath.row == 0 {
            print("0")
        }else {
            print("1")
        } is what I use inside the didSelectItemAtIndexPath func, but its not printing anything :/.